# Git branch naming convention for a minor revision to Readme.md

Tags: git, gitlab

I am new to git. I read through some naming conventions and saw different naming conventions for branches like hotfix/, bugfix/, feature/,etc. However, this is my first branch and all I did was update the readme with notes about required configuration settings. How should I name this branch?
I believe this minor update has to be a branch so that I can submit a merge request in gitlab. Please let me know if there are any helpful documentations or if I am approaching this incorrectly.

Comment: Is this a personal project or a project for your employer? Are you the only person working in this git repo or are you working with a team?

Comment: This is a project for my employer and working in a team.

Comment: You need to discuss branch naming conventions with your team. At the end of the day, their opinion about such things matter more than some random person on the Internet, even myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Branch names can be whatever you want. Feel free to establish your own conventions. Don't agonize over it too much.

The conventions for prefixes like `hotfix/`, `bugfix/` and `feature/` are intended for large projects and teams to organize their work. I rarely use these prefixes in my personal projects.

When working on a team project, we regularly discuss branch name conventions and agree as a group what they should be. On some teams, I've used these prefixes and on others just use an issue number to associate it with a ticket in GitLab, GitHub or Jira.